# Информация по каждому посетителю сайта с новой строки

Tags: php

Имеется скрипт который вписывает в файл base.php информация по каждому посетителю моего сайта 
в виде указаном в скриншоте: http://prntscr.com/6qlc22
Что нужно изменить в скрипте чтобы он вписывал информацию по каждому посетителю сайта с новой строки:

```
<?
$ip=getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
$date=date("d M Y, H:i:s");
$agent=getenv("HTTP_USER_AGENT");
$str=("
Data - $date
Ip - $ip
Browser - $agent
-------");
$log = fopen("base.php","a+");
fwrite($log,"\n $str \n" );
fclose($log);
?>
```

Comment: Разместите здесь ту часть скрипта, которая отвечает за запись данных в файл, чтобы сообщество смогло корректно ответить на ваш вопрос, а не заниматься гаданием на кофейной гуще.

Comment: <?
$ip=getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
$date=date("d M Y, H:i:s");
$agent=getenv("HTTP_USER_AGENT");
$str=("
Data - $date
Ip - $ip
-------");
$log = fopen("base.php","a+");
fwrite($log,"\n $str \n" );
fclose($log);
?>

Answer (score 1):

Скрипт записывает данные верно.

Скорее всего, неверно они выводятся. Чтобы переносы строк были как в файле, нужно обернуть вывод ваших логов в тег `<pre>`.

---

**Update:**  теперь я понял в чем ваша проблема. Вы пытаетесь открыть файл в браузере, обращаясь к нему напрямую и не видите расставленных вами переносов строк. Все это происходит потому, что вы сохраняете данные в файл с расширением `*.php`.

Смените расширение вашего файла, например, на `.txt` и проблема будет решена.

После этого обновите ваш код, записывающий данные в файл, чтобы сохранять данные в файл с новым расширением:

```
<?
$ip=getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
$date=date("d M Y, H:i:s");
$agent=getenv("HTTP_USER_AGENT");
$str=("
Data - $date
Ip - $ip
Browser - $agent
-------");
$log = fopen("base.txt","a+"); // Изменения в этой строчке
fwrite($log,"\n $str \n" );
fclose($log);
?>
```

Соответственно, теперь для просмотра логов нужно будет обращаться к файлу `base.txt`.

Comment: Как это будет выглядеть в скрипте ?

Comment: У меня встречный вопрос: как выглядит ваш скрипт для вывода данных на экран?

Comment: Я его выложил в ветке форума http://prntscr.com/6qm42h

Comment: Сейчас отчёт в браузере выглядет вот так http://prntscr.com/6qm4xa

Comment: Скрипт переписал и выглядет так http://prntscr.com/6qm5ky  .  За счёт количества точек выравнил отчёт.

Comment: Как вписать в него определение города и страны и запись в файл?

Comment: Я обновил свой ответ, чтобы ответить на ваш первый вопрос. Относительно вашего комментария: почитайте вот эту статью [Геолокация на PHP с помощью сервиса ipgeobase.ru](http://ross.vc/?p=204).

Comment: Спасибо за помощь !!!!  Как теперь определить город и страну и вписать в лог файл.

Comment: По ссылке выше вы можете найти ответ на этот вопрос. Если статья окажется непонятной, задайте новый вопрос на этом форуме с пояснением того, что конкретно вам непонятно в вопросе определения города и страны по IP и что вы попытались сделать сами. Я считаю, что на вопрос, заданный в заголовке, я вам уже ответил.

Comment: В скрипте который я указал надо вписать код определения города страны и чтобы было это всё записано в файл base.txt вместе с ip, датой и временем.

Comment: Пробовал привязать код с этой статьи http://ucozmagazines.ru/blog/opredelenie_goroda_po_ip_api_jandeks_kart/2013-09-04-42  но ничего пока не получается, может подскажете можно привязать этот код к моему скрипту?

Answer (score 1):

При таком формировании файла, каждая запись все-таки идет с новой строки). Видимо автор просматривает файл в Windows, а не Linux. Дело в том, что в Windows - стандарт перевода строки — `\r\n`, в Linux же просто — `\n`.

Чтобы при просмотре через блокнот, каждая запись выводилась с новой строки, измените код на этот:

```
$str = ("
Data - $date\r\n
Ip - $ip\r\n
Browser - $agent\t\n
-------");
$log = fopen("base.txt", "a+"); 
fwrite($log, "\r\n" . $str . "\r\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

При выводе можно использовать банальный `nl2br`.

Также я бы обратил внимание на http://php.net/manual/ru/function.stream-set-write-buffer.php

**UPD**

Если Вы выводите через `file_get_contents`, например, то это может выглядеть так:

```
$file = file_get_contents("/base.php");
echo nl2br($file);
```